# Defining function by overlapping cases in constructive logic

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

Is it possible to define a function by cases in intuitionistic logic where the cases possibly overlap and the function values disagree in the overlapping area? In particular, if I am working with real values, then I might have proof of $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x > 2 \lor x < 3$. Is it valid to define a function as follows?
$$
 f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N},\quad x \mapsto 
\begin{cases} 
 1 & \text{if } x > 2 \\
 0 & \text{if } x < 3
\end{cases}
$$

On the one hand, if I am thinking in terms of the Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov interpretation, then the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x > 2 \lor x < 3$ gives me a pair $(0, p(x))$ or $(1, q(x))$ (where $p(x)$ is a proof of $x > 2$ and $q(x)$ is a proof of $x < 3$), which I could then use to decide between the two cases. On the other hand, the function above is not classically well-defined: for $x = 2.5$, then $f(x) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$, which breaks extensionality. Classically, I could repair the above definition by writing
$$
\tilde{f} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}, \quad x \mapsto \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if } x > 2 \\
 0 & \text{if } \neg(x > 2) \land x < 3
\end{cases},
$$
essentially by asserting that the cases were exclusive. This trick doesn't work constructively though, since I don't necessarily have a proof that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x > 2 \lor \neg(x > 2)$.

Is such a definition valid in a constructive setting, then? If not, what modifications can I make to obtain a similar result?

Comment: But why do you think that is well-defined intuistionistically ? $2 < 2.5. < 3$ holds and thus the definition outputs two different values to for input 2.5. This means that it is not a function.

Comment: It is consistent with constructive mathematics (e.g., higher-order arithmetic or set theories like $\mathsf{CZF}$ and $\mathsf{IZF}$) that every function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, so your attempt cannot succeed.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am suspicious that it is not well-defined intuitionistically, but am not sure. Thinking informally, I can write a program which computes values in $\mathbb{N}$ like this, but I think it's just applying the trick for $\tilde{f}$, so I don't know if that means there is a trick to fix this or if it's simply invalid.

Comment: @HanulJeon In what sense must the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ be continuous? Naively, if I take the normal sense of a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, then that would mean that my only options for a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ are the constant functions.

Comment: Yes, it means every function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$ is continuous.

Comment: So in general, if I have a set $S$ and a proof $\forall x \in S, A(x) \lor B(x)$, then defining a function $g : S \to \mathbb{N}, x \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } A(x)\\ 0 & \text{if } B(x)\end{cases}$ is only valid if I can also prove $\forall x \in S, \neg(A(x) \land B(x))$, or do I still need to be careful even then?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\!$

Comment: @HanulJeon Thanks for the help! If you'll write that up as an answer, I'll go ahead and select it as the solution.

Comment: It can be possible to work around the impossibility to define a step function constructively.  One possibility is to accept that the function might not be "well defined" as here -- for example, in Gaussian elimination, while selecting a pivot you might choose to "give up" after a while if two pivot candidates are too close together, and the end result won't be different.

Comment: Another possibility is to define the domain to exclude the point of discontinuity, and then iterate approximations until you know what case you're in.  To take the example of Gaussian elimination again - you might restrict to only working on nonsingular matrices, and then iterate approximations to candidate pivots until you have a proof that one of them is nonzero.  (And if you incorrectly pass in a singular matrix, the algorithm will end up looping infinitely.)

Answer (score 3):

I've seen two constructs in such a context with a finite set of exhaustive cases, and a function for each case that takes the case as its domain:

>When all of the functions agree on the overlap of their domains, the construction pans out well, as you point out. That is to say, the functions are *compatible,* and the resulting function is the *gluing* of these functions—this is standard stuff you see in, for instance, sheafs of continuous functions.

>When it is not known whether the functions are compatible, I've seen the following type of workaround, which is usually phrased like this:

> If $X=X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n$, then given any $x\in X$, there is a way to effectively find an integer $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$ and $x\in X_k$. This effective procedure can be described as a function $h:X\to\lbrace 1,\cdots, n\rbrace$ such that $x\in X_{h(x)}$ for all $x\in X$. Hence, if $f_k:X_k\to Y$ for each natural $k$ with $1\leq k\leq n$, one may define $$f(x)=f_{h(x)}(x).$$

As you may be aware, the "procedure" being symbolized as $h$ here may not be functional—for example, if $X$ were the natural numbers, then $h(2+2)$ and $h(4)$ could yield different results. So the assertion that such a functional $h$ *exists* is a form of choice principle; as it turns out, you will only see this type of argument in use when $X$ is countable, and this is due to a lot of constructivist schools tending to accept countable choice. Hence, this construct depends on if *you* accept countable choice or not—and of course it depends on whether $X$ is countable or not.

In general, it's important to consider the *topology* of the sets being involved, as that is intimately related to the ways in which you can probe the space, its regions and its points. Thus, the method that is most reliable and natural with this outlook is, evidently, the gluing of compatible maps.

---

**Post scriptum.** Some people also take care, in the case of map gluing, to mention that this *also* utilizes a choice principle: the [principle of unique choice.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302037/mathematics-without-the-principle-of-unique-choice) I do not know much about the specifics of math without this principle, and most constructivists I know are fine with using it. It looks like the MathOverflow post is a good start, though.